# Group and sort JSON array of dictionaries by repeatable keys in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I have a json that is a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

I am getting it from MySQL with pymysql

```
[{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "test",
    "group": "test_group"
},
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "test",
    "group": "test2_group"
},
{
    "id": "456",
    "name": "test2",
    "group": "test_group2"
},
{
    "id": "456",
    "name": "test2",
    "group": "test_group3"
}]
```

I need to group it so each "name" will have just one dict and it will contain  a list of all groups that under this name.
something like this :

```
[{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "test",
    "group": ["test2_group", "test_group"]
},
{
    "id": "456",
    "name": "test2",
    "group": ["test_group2", "test_group3"]
}]
```

I would like to get some help, 
Thanks !

Comment: please post your code you tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for grouping of data.
Although I don't guarantee solution below to be shortest way but it should do the work.

```
# Your input data
data = [] 

from itertools import groupby

res = []
key_func = lambda k: k['id']

for k, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=key_func), key=key_func):
    obj = { 'id': k, 'name': '', 'group': []}
    for group in g:
        if not obj['name']:
            obj['name'] = group['name']
        obj['group'].append(group['group'])
    res.append(obj)

print(res)
```

It should print the data in required format.

Comment: @Eyal.D I've removed `is_new`. Look for the updated answer.